# Providing FontFamily on Window of WPF

Tags: wpf, font-family

I have using  `<Window FontFamily="Fonts/fontName.ttf#font Name"` on my existing Window and it works correctly.

But when I try to Create Window like this, the font isn't usable:

```
MainWindow newWindow = new MainWindow();
newWindow.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Fonts/fontName.ttf#font Name");
newWindow.FontSize = 16;
```

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf isn't solve your link, but thanks

Comment: Use a full Pack URI as mentioned in the comments to the answer of the question marked as duplicate. I've also edited that answer. There are also a lot of examples in the [online documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fontfamily(v=vs.110).aspx).